# How to get javascript array from URL with $_GET

Tags: php, javascript, url, post, get

I have checkboxes that are passed as an array to URL and on page reload I should get them back so that what is checked is remembered.

here is my javascript, array in question is 'entry_reason':

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function reload(nname, surname, birth_date, birth_country, birth_place, postal_code, address, residence, oib, license_number, license_iplace, passport_number, passport_iplace, entry_reason, myself, myselfeng)

{
// Setting the variable with the value of selected country's ID
var nname=document.getElementById('nname').value;
var surname=document.getElementById('surname').value;
var birth_date=document.getElementById('birth_date').value;
var c=document.getElementById('birth_country').value;
var city=document.getElementById('birth_place').value;
var postal_code=document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
var address=document.getElementById('address').value;
var residence=document.getElementById('residence').value;
var oib=document.getElementById('oib').value;
var license_number=document.getElementById('license_number').value;
var license_iplace=document.getElementById('license_iplace').value;
var passport_number=document.getElementById('passport_number').value;
var passport_iplace=document.getElementById('passport_iplace').value;
var entry_reason=[document.getElementById('entry_reason1').value, document.getElementById('entry_reason2').value, document.getElementById('entry_reason3').value, document.getElementById('entry_reason4').value, document.getElementById('entry_reason5').value, document.getElementById('entry_reason6').value, document.getElementById('entry_reason7').value];
var myself=document.getElementById('myself').value;
var myselfeng=document.getElementById('myselfeng').value;
// Sending the country id in the query string to retrieve the city list
self.location='blacklistprivateregister.php?nname=' + nname + '&surname=' + surname + '&birth_date=' + birth_date + '&birth_country=' + c + '&birth_place=' + city + '&postal_code=' + postal_code + '&address=' + address + '&residence=' + residence + '&oib=' + oib + '&license_number=' + license_number + '&license_iplace=' + license_iplace + '&passport_number=' + passport_number + '&passport_iplace=' + passport_iplace + '&entry_reason[]=' + entry_reason + '&myself=' + myself + '&myselfeng=' + myselfeng;
}
-->
</script>
```

I get URL that looks something like this:

```
http://xxxxxxxx.php?nname=ivo&surname=&birth_date=2012-11-08&birth_country=Algeria&birth_place=Benguela&postal_code=10000&address=%C4%8Ci%C4%8Dkovina%20222&residence=Zagorne&oib=1231231232131&license_number=21312323213&license_iplace=Zagreb&passport_number=000493243244&passport_iplace=Vara%C5%BEdin&entry_reason[]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&myself=aasddsad&myselfeng=asdadasd
```

Place with my input checkboxes is like this:

```
<legend><?php echo REASONFORENTRY_R; ?></legend>
        <?php 
            $e=array();
            if(isset($_POST['entry_reason'])){ $e=$_POST['entry_reason'];} 
            if($_GET['entry_reason']) {$e=$_GET['entry_reason'];} 
        ?>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="entry_reason[]" id="entry_reason1" class="check" value="1"  <?php if(in_array('1', $e)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/><?php echo ER1_R; ?></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="entry_reason[]" id="entry_reason2" class="check"  value="2"  <?php if(in_array('2', $e)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/><?php echo ER2_R; ?></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="entry_reason[]" id="entry_reason3" class="check"  value="3"  <?php if(in_array('3', $e)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/><?php echo ER3_R; ?></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="entry_reason[]" id="entry_reason4" class="check"  value="4"   <?php if(in_array('4', $e)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/><?php echo ER4_R; ?></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="entry_reason[]" id="entry_reason5" class="check"  value="5"   <?php if(in_array('5', $e)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/><?php echo ER5_R; ?></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="entry_reason[]" id="entry_reason6" class="check"  value="6"  <?php if(in_array('6', $e)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/><?php echo ER6_R; ?></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="entry_reason[]" id="entry_reason7"  class="check" value="7"  <?php if(in_array('7', $e)) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>/><?php echo ER7_R; ?></p>
```

I have 3 actions on site and for 2 of them I want checkboxes to be remembered:
1) Page reload on javascript function reload
2) Page reload on submit with error - this one works for now with $_POST

I presume that for 1st reload I should get all variable items from URL into $_GET and pass them on to $e variable but it doesn't seem to be working.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: No offense, but have you heard about loops? Do you understand `<form>` html element and what's it used for? The same question about `GET` and `POST` http request methods. Have you considered using single http-method (i.e. GET **or** POST) for all requests? And as a final workaround have you tried sticking with `$_REQUEST` superglobal rather than with `$_GET` and `$_POST`?

Answer (score -1):

In PHP use `json_encode($array);`

http://php.net/json_encode

In Javascript you have many ways to skin that cat. My solution is serialize this Array and send it back to PHP.

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: In your form you can use with jQuery `vars = $('#form').serialize()` and send it for PHP